# New command employing \multirow and \multicolumn

Tags: macros, multirow

I define a new command like this:

```
\newcommand{\rowcol}[4]{ %
    \multicolumn{#1}{#3}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#4}} %
}
```

I then use it inside the column as,

```
\rowcol{2}{2}{|c|}{Factor}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Replication}&Total \\ \cline{3-4}
```

Is there any mistake in doing this, I'm getting error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a redundant closing brace after `Factor`. The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\rowcol}[4]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{#3}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\rowcol{2}{2}{|c|}{Factor}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Replication}&Total \\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that if you put spaces before comment signs, you might as well omit those signs altogether.

Comment: Thank you, I should have seen that... I am sorry to ask such a question without debugging... But, thank you anyway